# changing jars order in classpath during runtime

Tags: java

Is there an option in java to change the order of jars file during runtime depends on parameter to the application.

Case1:
Input parameter with value true: jar A will be before jar B in the classpath

Case2:
Input parameter with value false: jar B will be before jar A in the classpath

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to do this. All required jar file are loaded as soon as they required for the first time. So i don't think this will add any value to your application.

Comment: This is a solution looking for a problem. You would have to explain *why.* If you want dynamic class loading, it is already available.

Comment: is there an option to make dynamic jar loading ,to control in the class path jars order.

Comment: No, but you can code it, according to your requirements, which you still haven't stated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only achieve this by manually loading the class at the startup of your application.

Take a look at this: [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

That way you can change the order in which the classes are loaded according to the parameter.

Comment: i can;t work in the levels of the classes i want to work in levels of jars file.